# Can you please identify these time travellers?

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Marty McFly (red shirt; with hoverboard) and The Doctor (brown overcoat; his TARDIS on the table) are easy.

**Who are the other three** (an elf in green, a guy in blue and a black bunny dinosaur)?

Comment: The elf is Link.

Comment: The rabbit is from Donnie Darko.

Comment: no Crono from Chrono Trigger :(

Comment: Presumably all of the _other_ time travellers will be turning up two weeks ago.  Or at a house party in 1999.

Comment: "Black bunny dinosaur" made my day.

Comment: Thumbs-up for the nicest title ever.

Comment: Please link to the creator of the picture if you can. Would be nice if they were credited.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Yes

---

### The scary rabbit is 'Frank' from [*Donnie Darko*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnie_Darko)

[image]
<sup>[img src](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/82/ba/6882ba4257c572bdef5187966ff57e2d.jpg)</sup>

> Do you believe in time travel?
> <sub>[**Frank**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/quotes/qt0380551), *Donnie Darko* (2001)</sub>

### The elf in the green is '[**Link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda#Link)' from [*Legend of Zelda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda)

[image]
<sup>[img src](http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/19600000/link-the-ocarina-of-time-19634128-228-316.jpg)</sup>

<sup>Thank you to [eyballfrog](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170334/can-you-please-identify-these-time-travellers/170336?noredirect=1#comment455645_170336) for pointing out that this might be the 'Ocarina of Time' version of Link.</sup>

### The guy with the brown coat is '[**The Doctor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who#The_Doctor)', from *[Doctor Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who)*

Presumably the [Tenth Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenth_Doctor), played by David Tennant:

[image]
<sup>[img src](https://www.fjackets.com/product_images/n/340/tenth_doctor_coat__41533_zoom.jpg)</sup>

<sup>Thank you to [Chris](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170334/can-you-please-identify-these-time-travellers/170336?noredirect=1#comment455688_170336) for providing a more accurate photo of the Tenth Doctor</sup>

### The cool guy with the hover board is '[**Marty McFly**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marty_McFly)' from the [*Back to the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future) series

[image]
<sup>[img src](http://blog.mytrendyphone.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/marty-mcfly-hoverboard.jpg)</sup>

### The one with purple hair is '[**Trunks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunks_(Dragon_Ball))' (or better known as 'Future Trunks') from the '*[Dragonball Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z)*' series

[image]
<sup>[img src](https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/d/db/Trunksmangacolor.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/185?cb=20160516024316)</sup>

---

## History

The earliest appearance of this image that I can find seems to be from the online T-Shirt shop - Shirtoid.com.

You can apparently purchase this art directly from them at http://shirtoid.com/139678/time-travelers-convention/

You can see that I'm correct (as usual) as the shirt has been 'tagged' with the following:

> Link, Marty McFly, Doctor Who, Donnie Darko, and Future Trunks

[image]